# Error in static_transform_publisher

Tags: rviz, transform, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I would a map with neato xv-11 and hector_slam in rviz. This is my launch file https://github.com/JanezCim/Neato-XV-11-Hector-SLAM/blob/master/neato.launch but when I type "$ rosrun tf static_transform_publisher" I have this message "static_transform_publisher exited due to not having the right number of arguments". What is it? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224507/error-in-static_transform_publisher/) by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2016-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to tell the `static_transform_publisher` which transform it should publish.
Check out the [tf wiki page here](http://wiki.ros.org/tf#static_transform_publisher).

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) on 2016-01-20**:
Thank you!